# Angular 4 RouteReuseStrategy impossible to store/retrieve siblings AND ALSO a non-sibling

Tags: angular, router, angular-routing, sticky, angular-router

If routing includes a route with no children, and **also** a route with children, it is impossible to store and retrieve the correct DetachedRouteHandle if all routes are to be detached and if the user navigates among the siblings and the parent.

So if I have these routes defined:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard',  component: DashboardComponent, data:{key: 'keyDashboard'}},
  { path: 'pages',
    component: PagesComponent,
    data: {key: 'keyPages'},
    children: [
      { path: 'A', component: PagesAComponent, data:{key: 'keyA'} },
      { path: 'B', component: PagesBComponent, data:{key: 'keyB'} },
    ]}
];
```

And a user navigates in order from dashboard to pages/A to dashboard to pages/B to pages/A, there is no way to not re-create the PagesAComponent.

This is because the router is checking the full tree, but when navigating to/from a child such as pages/A to a sibling it asks to store the route from below the parent 'pages' (just 'A' or 'B' in this case), but when navigating to a non-sibling it stores a route tree of 'pages/A' or 'pages/B'.

Here is a plunker:
http://embed.plnkr.co/DpYadGWx6PRHzSUKX2pK/

Click on dashboard, then pages/A, change value, then dashboard, then pages/B, 
then pages/A.   A is re-constructed at this point.

For a key in CustomReuseStrategy I am currently using the catenation of 'keys' defined in the router data (see computeSnapshotKey).   If I simply use the leaf 'key' (which does uniquely identify) the component I will get the angular error complaining it can't attach to a non-identical route.   This is because the DetachedRouteHandle represents pages/A instead of just A which is expected.

Anybody have a workaround or suggestion?

Thanks.